# Unhandled exception after moving the C# code to server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008, c#-3.0

We are having an internal web application developed using C#.net, MVC. Each time 100 members access the app. while using, automatically logging out in any of the systems and with out any error page/message.

It is not occurring in a specific time/ using service. After that anybody try to login into the app, getting error message like "user name/password wrong." till application pool restarts.

The issue is occurring only with in two/three days after moving the code from local to server. After three/four days, application is working fine.

I am struggling to know the issue from code side or application pool issue?

Comment: Take a look at the application pool memory, or set debug="true" and trace="on" in your web.config then access the site locally this may provide better error message feed back.

Comment: I had many unsuccessful attempts to replicate the issue in local.

Comment: Are you doing anything to catch errors and log their stack traces?

Comment: Actually, I used try catch on required conditions. But, there was no log.

Comment: Look at Database Connection Pools. You may be creating too many connection pools. Run SQL Profiler against the Database and observe how many new connection pools are created. You may not be closing you SqlConnection after using it. Ensure you have Sql connections closed after any CRUD operation to the database.